# In scala, can we use loops inside a recursive function?

Tags: scala, loops, recursion

I'm having troubles defining a recursive function in scala that uses a loop. The function should go through a range of coin denominations (the wallet) and if a certain condition is met, it returns a list of lists; if not, it calls itself again. Here is the code I wrote:

```
def subtractCoin(money: Int, wallet: List[Int], coins: List[Int], coinsSet: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {

  for (i <- 0 to wallet.length) {
    if (money - wallet(i) < 0) {
      if (money - coins.reduce(_ + _) == 0) (coinsSet :+ coins.sortWith(_ > _)) else coinsSet
    }
    else subtractCoin(money - wallet(i), wallet, coins :+ wallet(i), coinsSet)
  }
}
```

I got the following compiling error:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: List[List[Int]]
        for (i <- 0 to wallet.length) {
               ^
```

Why is it imposing the result type on the loop? Is there a way to use the loop? Would `foreach` be an alternative? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what happens if rangeOfCoins.length == 0?  Will it return a List[List[Int]]?

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry, my bad, rangeOfCoins in the error message corresponds to wallet (just corrected it). This condition is filtered in the code before calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens after the recursive call to `subtractCoin()` returns. Your `for` comprehension (the proper terminology) has no `yield` clause so the statement evaluates to `Unit`, which isn't what `subtractCoin()` is supposed to return. Thus the error.

Instead of advancing the index of `wallet`, it would probably be better to work with `wallet.head` and recurse with `wallet.tail`. (Indexing a `List` is not efficient.)

Also, what is the first rule of recursion? ---> *Test for the terminus condition!*